# Permission denied error in Python trying to close a window

Tags: python, textedit

I'm trying to close an open TextEdit window using Python. I can open the window just fine using:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.call(['open', 'allen_grammar.txt'])
```

But when I try to close the window using

```
p = subprocess.Popen( 'allen_grammar.txt')
p.terminate()
```

I get a permission denied error:

```
p = subprocess.Popen( 'allen_grammar.txt')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have full permissions on the file and I'm the admin of the computer.

Comment: did you try with `sudo` privileges?

Comment: yes.  That didn't work.

Comment: okay @kylefoley76, try open your python shell with `sudo python`, then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

The call to Popen should be like this:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe','allen_grammar.txt'])
```

I've used notepad since I don't have TextEdit, you can replace `'notepad.exe'` in the call to whatever text editor you want, `p.terminate()` should work fine afterwards

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. I'm getting a pid number but when I do `p.terminate()` nothing happens.  Also I have a Mac.  It also will not open the window. Maybe the problem is that I am putting in the wrong name of the app. I put in: `"/volumes/macintosh hd/applications/TextEdit.app/contents/macos/textedit"` because that is the only thing that would work.  I'm also getting a warning but it is not throwing an error: `2019-06-25 23:47:20.426 textedit[4280:283596] No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting`

Comment: If you have the pid (say saved at `pid`) you can do `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)` to terminate the process through the OS, which works on windows and linux, Mac uses unix (same as linux) so I believe it should support this as well.

Comment: Ok, that does not throw an error, but the problem is that popen does not open the file in a window.  Anyway I would like to close a specific window in textedit while leaving others open.  I was able to kill textedit by looking up the pid number on macos utilities but that kills the whole textedit app. I'm able to open a specific file using `subprocess.call` why can I not use that same module to close the window?

Comment: I would guess that the default behavior for mac `open` on text file would be a new tab in TextEdit, which is invoked by  `subprocess.call("open','text.txt')`, you could either find a command that terminates a specific tab in your program, or find out the right path to the app

Comment: If I could find someway to use the subprocess module to list the commands available in textedit that would really help. Another thing I don't get is that when I input `    p = subprocess.call(['close', 'allen_grammar.txt'])` I get an error: `FileNotFoundError` but when I put in `p = subprocess.call(['open', 'allen_grammar.txt'])` I don't get such an error.

Comment: Over at sharats.me the guy says that I can use command line with subprocess `subprocess.call('ls | wc -l', shell=True)` so If I can close the window with command line then that should be a solution.

Comment: Ok, I got python to print a calendar using `subprocess.call('cal',shell=True)` now if I can just get terminal to close a specific window, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a successful workaround.  I had to use Applescript and calling Applescript from Python goes like this:

```
os.system(f'''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "TextEdit" to close (every window whose name is "allen_grammar.txt")' ''')
```